# Drawing & creating the canvas on the android screen

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-canvas, ondraw

The code will run through an array. If the character 'X' is seen in the array, it will drawRect at the respective spot on the screen.

The problem is that the color isn't actually being drawn on the screen. Some of the android websites talked about how you need a canvas, bitmap, etc. etc.

My question: **What do I need to do to get the colours from the drawRect method to actually show up on the screen?**

```
package com.example.routedrawingtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Display;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    float scale_x;
    float scale_y;

    public void main(String[] args){
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();

        int screen_width = size.x;
        int screen_height = size.y;
        scale_x = screen_width/125;
        scale_y = screen_height/100;

    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) { 

        int i;
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
     paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
        int j;

        for (i=0; i<125; i++)
            for (j=0; j<100; j++)
                if (charMap[i][j]=='X')

                canvas.drawRect(i*scale_x, j*scale_y, scale_x,scale_y, paint);
    }

}
```

Comment: do some research before asking a question. For example ANDROID DOES NOT ?USE A MAIN METHOD...........

Answer (score 0):

The method `onDraw` is not called by an `Activity` to do what you want, you need to extend the class View and implement the method there. Until you learn more when you add the view to a parent, you have to give it an explicit size like `fill_parent` or it will not show up on the screen.
For example:

```
    public class Drawer extends View
    {
        Paint paint =  new Paint();

         public Drawer()
         {
             paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
             paint.setStrokeColor(Color.BlUE);
             // etc...

         }

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
      for (i=0; i<125; i++)
        for (j=0; j<100; j++)
            if (charMap[i][j]=='X')

            canvas.drawRect(i*scale_x, j*scale_y, scale_x,scale_y, paint);
    } 

    }
```

Add the view to your code via XML or via code like using it's fully qualified name:

XML:

```
     <com.example.comp.Drawer
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"<<<< specify a size
       etc...
     />
```